# Installing digilent adept 2 in linux can't run djtgcfg

Tags: linux, fpga

I recently installed digilent adept 2 on linux mint 17.3. when I try to execute djtgcfg or djtgcfg enum  I receive the error

```
djtgcfg: error while loading shared libraries: libdabs.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

libdabs.so exists in the following locations on my machine

```
/usr/lib/digilent/adept/libdabs.so.2
/usr/local/lib64/digilent/adept/libdabs.so.2
/home/han_solo/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/common/bin/lin64/digilent 
/digilent.adept.runtime_2.13.1-x86_64/lib64/libdabs.so.2.11.1
/home/han_solo/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/common/bin/lin/digilent
/digilent.adept.runtime_2.13.1-i686/lib/libdabs.so.2.11.1
/home/han_solo/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/digilent  
/digilent.adept.runtime_2.13.1-x86_64/lib64/libdabs.so.2.11.1
/home/han_solo/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin/digilent 
/digilent.adept.runtime_2.13.1-i686/lib/libdabs.so.2.11.1
/usr/local/lib64/digilent/adept/libdabs.so.2.11.1
/usr/lib/digilent/adept/libdabs.so.2.16.5
```

Each instance has read access. I also made sure that there was a copy in /etc/ld.so.conf.d and ran

```
$ sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: I also attempted fix #5 on this page https://lonesysadmin.net/2013/02/22/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `/usr/local` and search for **libdabs.so.2** in `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/local/lib64`, depending on where you installed it. Be sure to also check `/usr/local/lib/digilent/adept` and `/usr/local/lib64/digilent/adept`

If you don't find the file, you can try going to `/usr/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/common/bin/lin64/digilent` or `/usr/Xilinx/14.4/ISE_DS/common/bin/lin/digilent` (32-bit or 64-bit drivers path) and running `./install_digilent.sh`. After running it, try to find **libdabs.so.2** again.

If you find **libdabs.so.2**, copy its path and then look for the file `/etc/ld.so.conf`. Edit this file. Paste the path you copied before in the last line of this file and save it (you can run `sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf` to edit it, for example). Then, run `sudo ldconfig` in the terminal to update the cache. Afterwards, close your terminal and re openit. try to run `djtgcfg` again. It should work.

Obs.: When adding the path to **ld.so.conf**, you must put the whole path, without the file name. For example, if the file path is

```
/usr/local/lib64/digilent/adept/libdabs.so.2
```

then you should put `/usr/local/lib64/digilent/adept/` in the last line of your `/etc/ld.so.conf`